# is there anything like apt's debsums, but for snap packages?

Tags: ubuntu, security, snap

I'd like to check the integrity of my system and usually I use debsums. But now I begin to use snap packages system. Then I need something like debsums to check the integrity of all other packages. Does there exist anything like that?

Comment: No, AFAIK snap doesn't offer any checksum features available for users. A snap is more like a read-only virtual machine (container vm) running in it's own space.

Comment: @MichaelD.   What you say is a bit weird because a vm should be naturally sandboxed but when I run chromium (that is a snap package) I see that I can access read/write to my /home/ directory.

Comment: It is sandboxed, with some access granted by default, and some that have to be granted (much like you could share some folders with a VM). The snaps are read-only squashfs filesystems, which are loop-mounted for access. Squashfs already has some checksums built-in, I'd think mounting it might fail if the checksums are invalid.

Comment: @Lews docker was the first implementation of container virtualization. Snap and everything else is like docker (or based on it). So keep on reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine